# Onclick fill form fields in third party form iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, iframe

since last two days i've been trying to achieve to auto fill fields in third party form in iframe exactly like this

```js
$("#btn1").click(function() {
  $("#test1").val("10");
  $("#test2").val("1.5");
  $("#test3").val("1000");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Formula 1:
  <input type="text" id="test1" value="">
</p>
<p>Formula 2:
  <input type="text" id="test2" value="">
</p>
<p>Formula 3:
  <input type="text" id="test3" value="">
</p>
<p>What the answers to these formulas?</p>
<br>
<button id="btn1">Hint</button>
```

I have gone through so many tutes that i even forgot where i had started.

I have gone through [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152646/fill-input-text-forms-on-other-website-in-iframe) but it is not what exactly i want.

Another similar solution is here [Fill input field inside an iframe when link outside of iframe is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53680671/fill-input-field-inside-an-iframe-when-link-outside-of-iframe-is-clicked)

but the user is using her/his own javascript as jquery.postmessage.min.js

Any idea about how to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152646/fill-input-text-forms-on-other-website-in-iframe I found that question. Check this out

Comment: @dizefurkan already mentioned that in this solution link.

Comment: In Iframe, jquery will not work

Answer (score 0):

You can access the inner HTML of an iframe using something like this

```
document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.window.document.querySelector('Tag you wanna select')
```

You might encounter this error **blocked a frame of origin null from accessing a cross-origin frame**  . A fix to this is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983786/blocked-a-frame-of-origin-null-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame-chrome/29984435).

While this might just selected the select the element in the iframe, I'm still unsure if you can actually fill the form in the iframe.

Edit- Just tried it, you actually can alter the innerHTML of frame this way. Hope this helps.

Comment: Slightly shorter... `document.querySelector("iframe").contentDocument.querySelector("input[name=myfield]").value = "my value"`